# Yield results asynchronously in python using multiprocessing or twisted

Tags: python, multiprocessing, twisted

I have an embarrassingly parallel application where the order of the results don't matter.

I have a single function and a list of 1000 arguments on which it works. Each function returns quite a bit of data though.

I have written some multiprocessing code to parallelize it.

```
def _process_parallel(func, args_list, args_dict={}):
    num_tasks = len(args_list)
    num_tasks_returned_ptr = [0]
    def _callback(result):
        num_tasks_returned_ptr[0] += 1
    # Send all tasks to be executed asynconously
    apply_results = [__POOL__.apply_async(func, args, args_dict, _callback)
                     for args in args_list]
    # Wait until all tasks have been processed
    while num_tasks_returned_ptr[0] < num_tasks:
        #print('Waiting: ' + str(num_tasks_returned_ptr[0]) + '/' + str(num_tasks))
        pass
    # Get the results
    result_list = [ap.get() for ap in apply_results]
    return result_list
```

I'm finding that the memory footprint is too high. Currently the results of the functions are not discarded until all of the results have been processed.

What I would like to do instead is something where the results are not stored after they have been executed. Something like this:

```
def _process_parallel(func, args_list, args_dict={}):
    # Send all tasks to be executed asynconously
    for result in somepackage.apply_async(func, args, args_dict, _callback):
        yield result
```

I can't seem to find a way to to this in multiprocessing. I've heard good things about twisted, but I'm not sure if its overkill for this simple task.

Does anyone know how to make a python generator which computes results asynchronously and yields them as they come in?

Comment: in python 3: `concurrent.futures` has exactly that.  There's probably a backport out there for python 2, I haven't checked.

Comment: Why not just use `Pool.map()` instead of `Pool.apply_async`? Since you are just waiting for the results, using an `_async` variant is of little use here. And if I read the docs correctly, `apply` uses only one worker.